# Any suggestion on handling unwanted text in a textfield in ruby on rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so i have this problem i am trying to address. I have this textfield with the id of request_money

```
<input id="request_money" name="request[money]" size="30" type="text">
```

In this textfield i have a [watermark plugin that i am using](http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/) with the text "Not now" which is happening via jQuery

```
$("#request_money").Watermark("Not Now");
```

This works fine but the problem arrises when i submit the form and this field is only supposed to be a numeric field, but when i submit it blank it takes the text "Not now" and sends it in. I tried a few ways to handle this...First i tried with jQuery like this...

```
$('form').submit(function(){
if($("#request_money").val("Not now")){
$("#request_money").val("")
}
});
```

but for some reason it even clears out all the numeric values also...seems to always be true, not sure why

and second i tried in the rails model

using the errors

```
def validate 
  if money == "Not now" 
  money = ''
end
```

And rails did not like that...any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if()` check is *setting* the value, it needs to *get* the value and check it against the default, like this:

```
if($("#request_money").val() == "Not now"){
  $("#request_money").val("")
}
```

Depending on how your watermark plugin works, you may be able to do this in a generic way for all watermarked elements...if you can't I'd suggest changing the plugin to allow it, or example storing the watermark text in data, then you could do something like:

```
$(".watermark").val(function(i, v) {
  return v == $.data(this, "watermark") ? "" : v;
});
```

If your plugin stored the watermark text as the `"watermark"` [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) value, and say applied a class to easily identify the elements, you could do the check above to easily loop though and clear any with a default value just before submission.  It's just a suggestion, not sure which plugin or how much control you have over it, but it would solve this common problem with value-based watermarks.

Comment: not sure if that will work...i updated my question with the plugin